# optimization algorithm palindrome

Tags: c++

how to make this algorithm to display palindrome that was done with fewer permutations ?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    #define M 26


    bool isPalin(string str, int* freq)
    {

        memset(freq, 0, M * sizeof(int));
        int l = str.length();


        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
            freq[str[i] - 'a']++;

        int odd = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
            if (freq[i] % 2 == 1)
                odd++;


        if ((l % 2 == 1 && odd == 1 ) || (l %2 == 0 && odd == 0))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }


    string reverse(string str)
    {
        string rev = str;
        reverse(rev.begin(), rev.end());
        return rev;
    }


    void printAllPossiblePalindromes(string str)
    {
        int freq[M];

        // checking whether letter can make palindrome or not
        if (!isPalin(str, freq))
            return;

        int l = str.length();


        string half = "";
        char oddC;
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            /* This condition will be true at most once */
            if(freq[i] % 2 == 1)
                oddC = i + 'a';

            half += string(freq[i] / 2, i + 'a');
        }




        do
        {
            palin = half;
            if (l % 2 == 1)
                palin += oddC;
            palin += reverse(half);
            cout << palin << endl;
        }
        while (next_permutation(half.begin(), half.end()));
    }


    int main()
    {
        string str = "trtaccart";
        cout << "All palindrome permutations of " << str << endl;
        printAllPossiblePalindromes(str);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  Could you give us more of an explanation of what problem this algorithm is to solve?  E.g. "Print all permutations of the input string that are palindromes."  Also, while it is on-topic to ask for performance improvements, it is technically off-topic to ask for help making a specific change work.

Comment: @mdfst13 I'm not so sure I agree with "technically off-topic to ask for help making a specific change work"... what do you mean exactly by that?

Comment: Gigel, does your current code work as you want it to? Please add some more context to your question, I can recommend looking at [some tips for posting a good question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562)

Comment: @SimonForsberg It is off-topic to ask for help writing new code.  And technically speaking, that seems to be what is requested here:  new code with fewer permutations.  I'm suggesting that if performance help is requested, we may answer with a fewer permutations solution.  And other improvement suggestions.

Comment: I want to see the minimum number of permutations of a word so that it becomes a palindrome but do not know how to do that . How to check the displayed results of my program is the best solution and that it is the number of permutations between litere.Daca have another idea how I could do that a word has become a palindrome with a minimum number of permutations , await proposals.

Comment: @Gigel If this was your initial intent then the question would be better suited for StackOverflow as a algorithm question / modification. If you do still want this code reviewed then make sure to leave it open, I'm typing a review presently.

Comment: @mdfst13 It is off-topic to request new features, not for asking for specific refactorings (doing the same thing in a better way). If I understand this question correctly, it is asking for how to do the same thing with fewer iterations.

Comment: @Gigel it's possible to rephrase your text to make this question *obviously on-topic*. For example something like: "I'm looking for any possible improvements, but I'm especially interested in performance improvements, for example reducing the the number of iterations".

Comment: The whole 'return' part of `isPalin` can be reduced to `return l % 2 ==  odd;`

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, your code is pretty good though there are a few design an language features that can be used.

First, you use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` which I am unfamiliar with but I'm assuming includes a few appropriate standard C++ libraries. However, the standard C++ way would be to include each library as needed

```
#include <string>    // std::string
#include <iostream>  // std::cout
#include <algorithm> // std::reverse, std::next_permutation
```

There are many posts that warn programmers about using `using namespace std;` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice)) as well as using `#define` statements for constants ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637332/static-const-vs-define)). Though the biggest gain would probably be from renaming it from `M` to something like `ALPHABET_SIZE` (single letter variable names are often confusing).

Your function name `isPalin` is slightly confusing because it doesn't check if the string IS a palindrome but rather CAN IT BE a palindrome.

One thing that can affect performance greatly is to reduce unneeded copying. Your function signature `bool isPalin(string str, int* freq)` introduces a copy from the calling function into the `str` variable. Because this and all your functions just work based on the string and don't change it, this could be replaced by `const std::string&`

This first thing your `isPalin` function does is clear the `freq` array. But the C++ way to do it would be to clear it in the initialization like so:

```
int freq[M] = {}; // the {} initializes the whole array to 0
```

or the even more C++ way would be to use `std::array`:

```
std::array<int, M> freq;
```

and change your function to

```
bool isPalin(const std::string& str, std::array<int, ALPHABET_SIZE>& freq)
```

Another thing, I'd advise against using `l` to denote the string length (again because one letter variable names are confusing) and would encourage you to simply use `str.size()`

The construct

```
if (<code>)
    return true;
else
    return false:
```

is the same thing as

```
return <code>;
```

Everything else here is just a few optimizations. In `printAllPossiblePalindromes` you could call `half.reserve(str.size()/2)` to avoid needless reallocations. In `std::string half = ""`, setting it to the empty string doesn't actually do anything here.

your code here:

```
    palin = half;
    if (l % 2 == 1)
        palin += oddC;
    palin += reverse(half);
    cout << palin << endl;
```

doesn't actually need to build `palin` because it's only being printed. So you can do

```
    if (str.size() % 2 == 0)
        std::cout << half << reverse(half) << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << half << oddC << reverse(half) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Nitpicks

> ```
>     using namespace std;
> ```

You may want to read [Why is using namespace std bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)

> ```
>     #define M 26
> ```

This would be more readable as something like

```
    #define ALPHABET_SIZE 26
```

And this is C++, so it would be better written as

```
    constant int ALPHABET_SIZE = 26;
```

This will enforce type safety as well.

#### More naming

> ```
>     bool isPalin(string str, int* freq)
> ```

I would find this more readable as

```
    bool canBePalindrome(std::string candidate, int* letterCounts)
```

Not only does that write out palindrome so that you don't need to remember that that is what you meant, it better describes what you are asking.  It's not if the string is currently a palindrome, it's if the string could be a palindrome.

I prefer the names `candidate` and `letterCounts`.  Both because they are written out and because they (in my opinion) better describe the variables.

You can see here how it is clearer that `string` is in `namespace std`.  In your original code, that wasn't nearly as obvious.

#### Write robustly in the face of future edits

> ```
>         memset(freq, 0, M * sizeof(int));
> ```

It would be better to write

```
        memset(letterCounts, 0, ALPHABET_SIZE * sizeof(*letterCounts));
```

That way, if you change the type of `letterCounts` to something else in the future, this will change automatically with it.  In your original code, you could end up clearing memory outside the array or not clearing all the array if you changed the type to `short *` or `long *`.  By using the name, you ensure that won't happen.  It will always use the right type.

#### Favor range-based `for` loops

> ```
>         for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
>             freq[str[i] - 'a']++;
> ```

Rather than managing the loop manually, you can use the C++ `for` each form:

```
        for (char &c : candidate)
        {
            characterCounts[c - 'a']++;
        }
```

It is usually recommended to always use the block form of control structures even when you currently only have a single statement.  This helps clarify what is and is not supposed to be in the loop.

#### Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)

> ```
>         if ((l % 2 == 1 && odd == 1 ) || (l %2 == 0 && odd == 0))
>             return true;
>         else
>             return false;
> ```

You could more easily write this as

```
        // if there are an even number of letters in the candidate
        // then it can only be formed into a palindrome if all characterCounts are even
        // or if there are an odd number of letters there must be only one letter 
        // with an odd number of occurrences
        return candidate.length() % 2 == oddCount;
```

That gets rid of the `l` variable entirely (only used once in the revised code).

Saying `oddCount` rather than `odd` makes it clearer that we are counting.

We can return `true` or `false` directly, so we don't need to use the `if`/`else` construct.

We don't need two different clauses based on whether the length is odd or even.  In both cases, `oddCount` should match the remainder.

#### Single Responsibility Principle

> ```
>         if (!isPalin(str, freq))
>             return;
> ```

I'd break your original functions into two:

```
        countLetters(str, letterCounts);
        if (! canBePalindrome(str, letterCounts))
        {
            return;
        }
```

Now there is one function that generates the `letterCounts` and another function that uses them.  This saves us having side effects to a function that returns a Boolean value.  The side effect (generating the `letterCounts`) is now in a function that clearly has that purpose.

#### Keep it simple

If you change

> ```
>        char oddC;
> ```

to

```
        char oddC = 0;
```

then

> ```
>             palin = half;
>             if (l % 2 == 1)
>                 palin += oddC;
>             palin += reverse(half);
>             cout << palin << endl;
> ```

could be simpler

```
            std::cout << half << oddC << reverse(half) << std::endl;
```

Now you don't need `palin` at all, which is good since you don't declare it.

#### Do you just need the count?

In one of the comments, you say

> I want to see the minimum number of permutations of a word so that it becomes a palindrome but do not know how to do that .

If all you need is the count, then the code could be much simpler:

```
        int letterCounts[ALPHABET_SIZE] = {};

        countLetters(str, letterCounts);
        if (!canBePalindrome(str, letterCounts))
        {
            std::cout << "No palindromes can be made from '" << str << "'." << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        int palindromeCount = factorial(str.length() / 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            freq[i] /= 2;
            palindromeCount /= factorial(letterCounts[i]);
        }

        std::cout << "Number of unique palindromes that can be made from '" << str << "':  " << palindromeCount << std::endl;
```

Note that this assumes that your factorial results stay within the bounds that can be stored in an `int`.

This works because a factorial is simply the number of orderings of a certain number of elements.  We divide by `factorial(letterCounts[i])` because duplicate letters are not ordered.  So we divide out the number of orderings there would be if the duplicate letters had been distinguishable characters.  Note that `oddC` is always in the same place if there, so we don't need to count it (integer rounding after division handles that).  We only need to count the number of orderings of the first half of the string because it's a palindrome.  There's always just one ordering of the second half that will match the first half.

```
    int factorial(int n)
    {
        int result = 1;

        while (n > 1)
        {
            result *= n--;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This is an example of how the `factorial` function might be written.  You can change the return type to `unsigned long` or bigger if you start having overflow.

If you actually need the palindromes listed, I don't see how you could do it in fewer iterations.  The `std::next_permutation` already guards against duplicate strings.  You have to go through that loop at least once per palindrome.